# Quartz scheduler can't run after add RabbitMQ.dll in production

Tags: rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler

Before Sometime (one week), my application was working perfectly. All schedulers were working perfectly. At that time we use MSMQ for queue purposing.

Now, we Implement and transfer all MSMQ to RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ (with priority) is working perfectly but now quartz scheduler is stopped to work?

We use quartz version 1.0.2.3
RabbitMQ Version 3.6.0

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

RabbitMQ code snippet:

```
var factory = GetConnectionFactory();
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    IDictionary<String, Object> args = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                    channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
                    args.Add("x-max-priority", 3);
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, args);
                    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, "", args, consumer);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
                        ProcessMessageFromQueue(message);
                        Log.Info("Message Received from " + queueName + ": "  + message + " , ChannelId : " + channel.NextPublishSeqNo + " ,ea:" + ea.DeliveryTag);
                        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                        //MessageQueueMessage messageQueueMessage = Utility.DeserializeObject<MessageQueueMessage>(message);
                        DeleteRedisVAriableByKey(message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Scheduler Snippet -

```
NameValueCollection properties = null;
    ISchedulerFactory sf = null;
    IScheduler sched = null;
    JobDetail jobDetail = null;
    Quartz.CronTrigger trigger = null;

    properties = new NameValueCollection();
    properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteServer";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";
    properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
    sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    sched = sf.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();              
    jobDetail = new JobDetail("MyJOb", "default", typeof(MyClass));
    trigger = new CronTrigger("MyTrigger", "default", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CronExpression"]);
    sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of the thread.

We have a parameter for no. of thread for quartz. suppose, it's value is 10.

We start one rabbitmq queue on start job by quartz.

You see in the code above, in rabbitmq start method, there is while loop.
so it never ends.

after trigger job second time, it creates one more consumer and it never ends.

after some time thread goes near to thread limit.

once threads reach to thread limit, no new thread created. it stopped our scheduler.